# How to enable organization admins can login as any user in cas server SSO

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, cas

We are using Cas server for SSO. I need to implement admin user to login as any user.

For example:-
I have a user like admin, Joe, Jim, Jose.
If the user is an admin, he should be able to login to an application as Joe/Jim/Jose.

May I know how we can implement it using central authentication server(CAS).

Thanks in advcance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrogate authentication (impersonation), sometimes known as sudo for the web, is the ability to authenticate on behalf of another user.

The two actors in this case are:

- The primary admin user whose credentials are verified upon authentication.
- The surrogate user, selected by the admin, to which CAS will switch after credential verification and is one that is linked to the single sign-on session.

Example use cases for impersonation include:

- Logging into an application on behalf of a user to execute and make changes.
- Troubleshoot a bothersome authentication experience with an application on behalf of another user.

Ref: https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/installation/Surrogate-Authentication.html